# Adding up array elements in php table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i wanted to ask I would I add up the points of all the drivers in the table produced below by the following code as this only displays points of all the drivers in each row ... There is a table Points which has points, position and a table Drivers having forename, surname.

```
    <?php
session_start();

if ( !isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) ) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
    $con=mysqli_connect("xxxxx","xxxxx","xxxxx","xxxx");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Drivers.forename, Drivers.surname, Teams.name, Teams.engine, Points.points
    From Drivers, Teams, Points");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th>Team Name</th>
    <th>Engine</th>
    <th>Points</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['forename'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['engine'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['points'] . "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: Just store the points in a variable. Add to it in each loop. Then echo it out. Easy.

Comment: If you only need the total points, then you can run `SUM()` on that column. However, if you're going to display the table anyways then just sum it with PHP instead.

Comment: You are doing a JOIN even though you don't know it.  You need WHERE clause in there.

Answer (score 0):

in your code, before the $while

```
     $counter=0
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $counter += $row['points'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['forename'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['engine'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['points'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}

 echo $counter; //echoes sum of points
```

Comment: Hi, The code you have given us doesn't not seem to work because it adds up all the points in the table but if i only want the points of each driver to add up and make it display in the point column , how do i do it? Thank you . P

Comment: I'm not sure i follow, the table holds a list of all your drivers, the $row['points'] should come from the database as a number.

What exactly do you want to sum? all your drivers? are your driver records unique in the database?(one row per driver?) 

does $row['points'] return anything at this moment?

Comment: I am summing up the points of the drivers but the thing is the drivers with the same name have different points in many rows and I want to sum all of their points in one row with their name and so how do I sum up the points of each driver and display their name and total point in one row. Driver Table: id, Forename, Surname Points Table: postion, points Patrick